# Passing parameters to Docker container

Tags: docker

I create a container docker. Which should give the following:

```
docker run --rm container1
> Hello World!

docker run --rm container1 Bob
> Hello Bob!
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo", "Hello"]
CMD ["World!"]
```

My output:

```
docker run --rm container1
> Hello World!

docker run --rm container1 Bob
> Hello Bob
```

I have a loss "!"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem might be coming from an underlaying incomprehension of string concatenation done by your Ubuntu shell

```
$ echo "Hello" "I" "am" "a" "developer"
Hello I am a developer
```

This works because the shell does not have a concatenation operator. So actually feeding echo with strings will make an `echo` of all those strings concatenated, there is no real black magic in that, and, as far as I know, the strings are concatenated in the order they are passed to `echo`.

Now what you are really trying to achieve here could easily be done with [`printf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) that can substitue a format from arguments:

```
printf 'Hello %s!' 'Bob'
> Hello Bob!
```

More info about printf substitution could be found [there](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf#syntax).

So if your `Dockerfile` would be:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ENTRYPOINT ["printf", "Hello %s!"]
CMD ["World"]
```

You will get your expected result.

```
$ docker build -t demo .

$ docker run --rm demo 
Hello World!

$ docker run --rm demo Bob
Hello Bob!
```

Comment: I did not know that there is a printf implementation in the shell

Answer (score 9):

> CMD :

The main purpose of a **CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container**. These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit the executable, in which case you must specify an ENTRYPOINT instruction as well.

> ENTRYPOINT :

**Runs the container to not to override the executable** which is specified in the image. The use of ENTRYPOINT sends a strong message that this container is only intended to run this one command.

Hence in your case when you run :

```
docker run --rm container1 Bob
```

the CMD is replaced with the string Bob and hence the result.

There can **only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile**. If you list more than one CMD then only the **last CMD will take effect.**

Hope this helps.

More on [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

**EDIT : Adding a basic example to demonstrate how to get parameters from command line.**

```
#cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ping"]
```

In the above docker file the command(CMD) to execute has not mentioned.It indicates that the container expects some arguments when it is started.It can be provided through command line as below:

```
docker run --dns=172.24.100.50 -it stack:2.0 -c 1 google.com
PING google.com (216.58.197.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maa03s21-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.78): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=68.2 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---

1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
```

The same can be achieved by adding the paramters into the dockerfile using CMD as below:

```
cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ping"]

CMD ["-c", "1", "google.com"]
```

Now run the container without providig an paramaters while starting:

```
docker run --dns=172.24.100.50 stack:4.0
PING google.com (216.58.197.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maa03s21-in-f78.1e100.net (216.58.197.78): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=50.0 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
```

**EDIT 2 :**

If you are looking specifically, then you can run the container as

```
docker run --rm container1 Bob!
```

As far as I know no option to insert in between as you need.

Comment: No, it does not help (((I've read everything, I can not understand how to get the parameter from the command line docker run use inside the container

Comment: can you check now..added some more info using an example.

Comment: Thank you! I understand how your example works, but it does not help to solve my problem in any way. I need to insert the passed parameter in the middle of the output line: "Hello <arg>!"

Comment: do you mean " Hello Bob World"...sumthing of this sort ??

Comment: Yes, only "World" change on "!"

Comment: Cheating: "docker run --rm container1 Bob!". 
The task should be solved in a general way: "....Text.....<arg>....Text..."

Answer (score 0):

This is normal

When you launch

`docker run --rm container1`

it uses the command

`echo`

with the argument

`World !`

When you add

`Bob`

it replaces

`World!`

by

`Bob`

see

[What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)

for more details

See also

https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/nethogs/

it monitors by default wlan0, but if you want to monitor say eth0, you will just add eth0 at the end of the

`docker run`

command, and wlan0 (the default) will be replaced by eth0

Comment: It does not help (((I've read everything, I can not understand how to get the parameter from the command line docker run use inside the container

Comment: try `docker run --rm container1 "Bob!"`

Comment: Cheating))))) It is interesting to output lines of type: "Text <arg> Text"